# Php Security Dilemma

Tags: php, mysql, ios

I am working on an ios app and calling PHP files through it. It is all functioning fine, but my issue is that if I simply type in the URL of my browser I can easily run the php files. Which is not very safe since one of my queries I run is to get the answers to the puzzle stored in the database. Wouldn't be much of an app if you could just type in the URL to get the solutions.

I return to the app from echo, and just pull what I need from that string. Is there a way to hide the string from browsers but make it visible to my app?

Comment: You could instead of echoing it return the answer. What I'd do is place whatever code you have there inside a function that runs the queries and returns whatever you need to your app. You'd of course have to do the actual printing inside of the app.
I'm sure there's also a way to prevent access to this file on some parameter using htaccess - but I can't think of it at the moment. I'm assuming this query is done via the users phone, and not through some sub-server?

Comment: @Marcus A PHP function can't magically "return" data to an external app; they're running on different computers, so have to communicate somehow across the Internet.

Comment: The only thing that distinguishes your app's HTTP client from a regular browser is the logic for how to generate requests to your API. It's not difficult to reverse engineer how you generate these requests, so I would just use a custom user agent and block all requests without that specific user agent.

Comment: @IMSoP I'm under the assumption that the request is done through an HTTP client. If I make a request to that, would it not return the value of the function being called with that HTTP Client? I did this when developing my app for Windows Phone.

Comment: @Marcus An `echo` in PHP writes text to the HTTP output, which is the only way of "returning" anything to the HTTP client that made the request. If that client is embedded in an app, it can use that data how it likes; but if that client is a browser, it will just show it on the screen. The server cannot change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a special token.

Like a 'secret key'.

This is probably the easiest but pretty easy to get the secret key via sniffing or reverse engineering.

If someone want to stole the data returned by the request, they will find the way easily. There is now way to prevent this permamently.

Comment: So right now I am passing "?id=1&type=3". Are you saying send like "?id=1&type=3&secret=secretkey"

Comment: IMSoP's solution is more viable if the function is used to check whether or not the user provided the correct answer.

Comment: Sending the key itself is the easiest thing to break, because you only need to see one URL to know the secret. If you use the secret to "sign" each request, you don't have to reveal it like this, so an attacker would have to find it inside the app's code.

Comment: @MarcusFrölander I'm not trying to verify the correctness of the answer, just hide the solutions from the outside world, and the key parameter will at least add a little more security, which is why I went with this answer

Comment: @cmlaiter I realize that, and I see this is exactly what OP needs. Goo idea! :)

Comment: @cmlaiter: How is this any different from just accessing the URL directly? If the secret key is static, it's just part of the URL that you don't want people with browsers to visit.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than returning the answer from the PHP script, make the app send an attempted solution, and have the server return "yes" or "no" based on whether it matches the answer in the DB.

As an additional protection against cheating, you could include a secret key in the app that must be used to "sign" the request (basically, calculate cryptographic_hash(secret_key + request) on both ends and check they match). Bear in mind that a dedicated cheater could reverse-engineer the compiled code to find this key, but it makes their life a bit harder.

You can also code the server to detect if lots of requests are coming from one place in quick succession, to prevent people doing "brute force" trial and error to find the right solution. Again, this isn't unbreakable, but might make some people give up.

**Edit** Since you want to keep the answer verification in the app rather than rearrange things so it takes place on the server, there is a halfway house: instead of the full details of the solution, the server could return a *hash* (one-way encryption) of it. That way, the app can still check that the solution it has is correct, by calculating the same hash, but anyone just reading the data cannot work out what the solution is, other than by brute force.

Comment: Making the app return true or false depending on the answer submitted is actually a very viable and swift way of solving the issue. In addition to having a hashed user agent, this would be the ultimate solution in my book. Good thinking!

Comment: I am getting the puzzle from the database with the solution and then in the app using my code to make it in a guessable form. So I check the solution in the app, but just use the server to hold all the soluions.

Comment: @cmlaiter You asked how to improve your app. If you don't want to change how it works, why ask?

Comment: @Marcus The User-Agent string is just another part of the request; another place to stash a secret key, but not much harder to sniff and copy than the URL itself.

Comment: @IMSoP Regardless of what I do I need to get the solutions from the server, that's how the app functions. So I always need to send the solutions in an echo. The question was posed as how to ensure it isn't easily visible. I appreciate your suggestions, but it doesn't work with how the app is built.

Comment: @cmlaiter Fair enough, if you're not willing to make such a major change to the app at this stage, then you'll have to accept that the design you've gone with has this security flaw. You'll need to make *some* change to the app whatever solution you choose, though, so saying "my app doesn't work that way" seemed an odd response.

Comment: @cmlaiter I've edited my answer with a suggestion which requires less change to the app structure.

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER: This is complicated :P**

You could have a PHP file that provides a token and stores it.

Then write a reversable argorythm that takes that string, encodes it (maybe using ASCII values of characters separated by a dot and each multiplied by a constant) and sends it to the server.

The server decodes it (for my example: explode by a dot, divide by constant, convert each number to its ASCII character and implode the array)

And if the decoded string matches the one stored on the server do whatever and regenerate the token.

Even if a hacker gets the token that the server sends, he won't be able to encode it without knowing the algorythm AND the constant.

Comment: Definitely a possibility but your disclaimer says it all lol. Will definitely consider though, thanks

Comment: The security of this approach hinges on the obscurity of the algorithm, which is not hard to figure out when you have the actual program to decode the responses. All you need is a jailbroken device and someone bored enough to disassemble that portion of the app. The most secure way to do this is to just have the server validate responses.

Comment: It's always better to let the server do the risky things but this would be the best way I KNOW OF to do this client side.

Also, I never had an iOS device so I didn't know how easy it was to decompile apps. Thanks for the warning BTW :)